# Understanding Python Map function

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am new to python and i am trying to understand the map() function, but i haven't been able to understand from past questions.

For example, I have a class called `Table` that has a constructor that instantiates a `Table` object. I would like to create a list of table objects called `table_objects_list`. I can do this using a for loop but I want to learn pythons map() function.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of the kind of output you're expecting?

Comment: Why do you want to use `map()` vs a list comprehension? E.g. `list(map(func, iterable))` can be written `[func(i) for i in iterable]`

Comment: You should post some code showing how you tried to use `map` to make `table_objects_list`.